# Laravel Permanent Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, url-rewriting

We are about to migrate our company website from standard .php website to Laravel. We kept the same url structure except that the new url's don't use .php at the end of the file name.

We want to allow our customers to still use the old url ( www.sampledomain.com/faq.php ) with the .php at the end, but redirect them to the new clean url without the .php ( www.sampledomain.com/faq ) if our users paste the old url in the browser address bar.

Any ideas in how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I did not ask this question correctly. That's why I did not get any answers.

Here is the .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have a regular php website and you are migrating to Laravel and keeping the same url structure except .php.

This will ensure that your customers that already have bookmarks of your website, for example " www.sampledomain.com/faq.php " could paste that in to the browser and you want it to automatically remove the .php extension and return the clean Laravel url like: www.sampledomain.com/faq

Just add that rule to your root .htaccess